# How to use thermal printer in laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel-5, thermal-printer

I m trying to do web application for restaurant in Laravel 5.4.
But i don't know how can i print receipt using thermal printer.
Please suggest me best way to print data on thermal printer in laravel.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

you can use **window.print()**

here is my code for invoice printing on thermal printer

```
<p align="center"><input type="button" id="pr" value="Print" onclick="printpage()" class="btn btn-success" /></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function printpage() {
         var printButton = document.getElementById("printingDiv");
         printButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';

        document.title = "";
        document.URL   = "";

        window.print();
        printButton.style.visibility = 'visible';


    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will try this one.

Answer (score 2):

I recently use Mike42/escpos-php for my minithermal M-58 POS printer. This is a php plugin that will connect your php app with minithermal printer through network. This is my simple code to print some words on minithermal printer.

```
try {
        // Enter the share name for your USB printer here
        //$connector = "POS-58";
        //$connector = new WindowsPrintConnector("POS-58");
        $connector = new WindowsPrintConnector("smb://yourPrinterIP");
        /* Print a "Hello world" receipt" */
        $printer = new Printer($connector);
        /* Name of shop */
        $printer->selectPrintMode(Printer::MODE_DOUBLE_WIDTH);
        $printer->setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_CENTER);
        $printer->text("POS Mart\n");
        $printer->selectPrintMode();
        $printer->text("Today Closing.\n");

        $printer->feed();
        /* Title of receipt */
        $printer->setEmphasis(true);

        $printer->feed(2);

        /* Cut the receipt and open the cash drawer */
        $printer->cut();
        $printer->pulse();
        /* Close printer */
        $printer->close();
        // echo "Sudah di Print";
        return true;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $message = "Couldn't print to this printer: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
        return false;
    }
```

All you need is to add your printer IP to your php printconnector code or if you use usb cable to connect to your printer, you can use your own ip as php printconnector code.

Answer (score -1):

try this code :
$connector = new WindowsPrintConnector("smb://computername/Receipt Printer");